Is there a way to find all the submodules of $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}] ^2$?
Let $R = \mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ be the  Laurent polynomials ring over the integers. Consider the R-module $M = R^2 =  \mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}] ^2$. Is there a way to find all the submodules of $M$? We know that $M$ is Noetherian, hence every submodule is finitely generated.
Where I got this question from: I am hoping to determine all the quotients of $M$, which is equivalent to finding all the submodules of $M$.
Has this been studied before? Any reference or insight will be really appreciated.

Well, they correspond to the $S$-submodules of $S^2$ containing $(st - 1, 0)$ and $(0, st - 1)$ where $S = \mathbb{Z}[s, t]$; and each such submodule has a Groebner basis.  Not sure how useful that would be.

$\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]=R$ is a PID, so you can use structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID to conclude that every submodule of $R^2$ is free of rank at most 2, and much more!

@I'mRepresentable I don't think $R$ is a PID

Oh yes, for some reason I thought it was over a field. $R$ is definitely not a PID since it has Krull dimension 2.
